# Strange certificates when updating with etckeeper in ArchLinux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, updates

I just updated my arch distro and got this:

```
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/02756ea4.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/2c11d503.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/32888f65.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/3929ec9f.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/451b5485.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/559f7c71.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/608a55ad.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/7719f463.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/87229d21.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/9168f543.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/9479c8c3.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/9c3323d4.0
create mode 100644 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/Certplus_Root_CA_G1.pem
create mode 100644 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/Certplus_Root_CA_G2.pem
create mode 100644 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem
create mode 100644 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem
create mode 100644 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G1.pem
create mode 100644 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G2.pem
create mode 100644 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G3.pem
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/d8317ada.0
create mode 120000 ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/dc99f41e.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/02756ea4.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/2c11d503.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/32888f65.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/3929ec9f.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/451b5485.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/559f7c71.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/608a55ad.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/7719f463.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/87229d21.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/9168f543.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/9479c8c3.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/9c3323d4.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/Certplus_Root_CA_G1.pem
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/Certplus_Root_CA_G2.pem
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G1.pem
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G2.pem
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G3.pem
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/d8317ada.0
create mode 120000 ssl/certs/dc99f41e.0
```

but it's very strange because this is not a webserver of any kind. Should I be worried about any kind of malware here?

Answer (score 1):

CA certificates have **nothing to do with being a webserver**. In particular, they're mainly needed by TLS *clients*, since it's the client who cares about verifying the server's own certificate. Every OS ships with such a list.

There exist many non-HTTP uses of TLS (such as email SMTP/IMAP traffic), but even the same HTTPS is used by many non-"web" programs – e.g. many `pacman` mirrors use https://, thus it also needs the CA certificate collection.

On Arch Linux, the primary list of "trusted certificate authorities" is **`ca-certificates-mozilla`**, split off Mozilla's `nss` package. In other words, it's the same as what Mozilla puts into Firefox, thus you can cross-check all newly added certificates against [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?component=CA%20Certificates&product=mozilla.org) and very often against Google's [Chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) (which maintains its own list). The OpenTrust/Certplus certificates seem to be merely renewals ([bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1025095) and [chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=385090)), as is the HARICA one ([bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1201423)).

Note that the master copies of trusted CAs are installed to **`/usr/share/ca-certificates`** (not tracked by etckeeper). What you're seeing in `/etc` is merely output of automated conversion into OpenSSL-compatible format (the `????????.0` symlinks being OpenSSL "hashed" names); see the *update-ca-trust(8)* manual page for how to update it.